# Custom DataGridView column sort based on Value not Formatted value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5, datagridview

I have a custom `DataGridView` cell I'm using to display the contents of `MyType` objects.  To control how they're being formatted I'm overriding the `GetFormattedValue()` and `FormattedvalueType` methods of `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` because in this case I don't want to use the default `ToString()` method.  The problem is that when I do this the `DataGridView` is sorting the column by the string in `FormattedValue` instead of by `Value`.

I'm not seeing a method I can override to change the sort behavior of the column.  While I know I can, I don't want to have to write custom `DataGridView.Sort()` methods because I'm using `MyType` columns in multiple `DataGridView`s.

Answer (score 1):

Are you filling the DGV manually, or using databinding ?

In the former case, you can handle the SortCompare event, as explained in the link posted by SwDevMan81.

In the latter case, make sure your `MyType` class implements `IComparable`. This implementation will be used by the DGV to sort the data.